# Export glTF 2.0 from Python Problems

Tags: python, export, gltf

This is my first question posted. I have been working on trying to export my blend scene (all objects, only 5 low poly objects) to a glb or gltf file using python script. I have tried the `bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf()`  function but it kicks out an error from the init.py line 73 & 76 that the exporter is calling.

Everything I can find (not much) says its looking for a UI to launch the exporter. I am able to export via the UI without issue, so the problem is in the code, I think. Does anyone have a working glTF code for Blender 2.91? Are any other versions working? Is there another add-on that has a working function?

your assistance is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Probably https://developer.blender.org/T83188. It only affects 2.91. Try upgrading to 2.93.